# Automatically generating documentation about the structure of the database

Tags: hadoop, hive

There is a database that contains several views and tables.
I need create a report (documentation of database) with a list of all the fields in these tables indicating the type and, if possible, an indication of the minimum/maximum values and values from first row. For example:

```
.------------.--------.--------.--------------.--------------.--------------.
| Table name | Column |  Type  |   MinValue   |   MaxValue   |   FirstRow   |
:------------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------:
| Table1     | day    | date   | ‘2010-09-17’ | ‘2016-12-10’ | ‘2016-12-10’ |
:------------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------:
| Table1     | price  | double | 1030.8       | 29485.7      | 6023.8       |
:------------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------:
| …          |        |        |              |              |              |
:------------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------:
| TableN     | day    | date   | ‘2014-06-20’ | ‘2016-11-28’ | ‘2016-11-16’ |
:------------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------:
| TableN     | owner  | string | NULL         | NULL         | ‘Joe’        |
'------------'--------'--------'--------------'--------------'--------------'
```

I think the execution of many queries

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) as max_value, MIN(column_name) as min_value
FROM table_name
```

Will be ineffective on the huge tables that are stored in Hadoop.

After reading documentation found an article about "[Statistics in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev)" 
It seems I must use request like this:

```
ANALYZE TABLE tablename COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;
```

But this command ended with error:

*Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ColumnStatsTask*

Do I understand correctly that this request add information to the description of the table and not display the result? Will this request work with view?

**Please suggest how to effectively and automatically create documentation for the database in HIVE?**

Comment: Your min/max query will be ineffective if you run it once for **each** column, but if you run for all columns at once, it won't be much worse than computing stats *(which may sample the data, but will compute much more complex stuff than Min/Max...)*

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter thanks for your answer.

The database lives its life :) and during the month may be new tables or fields created. I plan to generate a report once a week.

If it was a small relational database, I would use the script for generation a lot of queries min/max and for a reasonable time, gathered information about tables. But on the scale of hadoop this approach take (I think) a lot of time and computing resources. What do you think?

Comment: IMHO Hadoop is very good at running full scans of huge datasets (as long as there are not too many concurrent full scans)...

Comment: And by the way, if the datasets are indeed huge, then they are probably partitioned by date/time, so that you would scan each partition only once if your reporting strategy is smart.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter yes, tables have partitions. Use the information about partitions is a good idea, but how about the VIEWs?

Comment: Usually, views display the same data as the underlying tables, but with something more (predefined joins, predefined cleanup) and/or something less (skip columns, skip rows because refer to another Business scope). So, do these views require a functional documentation - yes. Do they require a technical documentation (i.e. data profiling) - depends on what your Business wants.